# Prove inquality involving factorial

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

This is part of an analysis problem I'm working on.

Show that:

$ \frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + ... < \frac{3}{(n+1)!}$

After some algebra I got

$ \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} + \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)} + ... < 2$

Now I'm stuck.

Comment: left hand side must converge because the terms tend to 0.

Comment: Convergence doesn't follow from the fact that the terms tend to 0. But because e = sum(1/n!) the left hand side surely converges.

Comment: "... **must** converge because the terms tend to zero"?  This is so false...

Comment: @jooi thanks for pointing that out. so how would you go about proving this?

Comment: The Ratio Test also settles it easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n \geq 0$, you have

$$ \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} + \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)} + \cdots$$
$$ \leq
  \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4} + \cdots $$
$$ < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \cdots = 1 < 2$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Compare the left side to a geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

By induction:

$e^x=1+x+x^2/2+x^3/3!+...+x^n/n!+...$

So if $x=1$

$e=2+1/2+...+1/n!+...$

If $n=0$ (in your formula) we get:

$3>1+1/2+...+1/n!$

which is clearly true since $3>e-1$.

If for $n$ is true then:

$\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + ... < \frac{3}{(n+1)!}$

so:

$\frac{1}{(n+2)!} + \frac{1}{(n+3)!} + ... <\frac{1}{(n+2)}\frac{1}{(n+1)!} +\frac{1}{(n+2)}\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+ ... < \frac{1}{(n+2)}\frac{3}{(n+1)!}=\frac{3}{(n+2)!}$

and we've proved the statement for $n+1$

Answer (score 0):

Well... you've finished!!!

Assume it's true...

$\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + \cdots < \frac{3}{(n+1)!}$

Now multiplying both side for $(n+1)!$  follows that

$1 + \frac{1}{(n+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} + \cdots... < 3$ (1)

Observing that for fixed positive $n$ the inequality $\frac{1}{n + 2 + k} < \frac{1}{2}$ for each $k$ positive the left side of (1) is of course less than

$1 + \frac{1}{(n+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} + \cdots... < \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^k = 2 < 3$

Then our assumption was correct!!!